# Send Unicode SMS via SMPP

Tags: java, unicode, smpp, jsmpp

I want to send sms iwth unicode characters via SMPP (JSMPP library). I know that Data Encoding must be 8 for it & sms length is 70 character. But when I try this, I get sms with Chinese symbols. Here is my code:

```
ESMClass esmClass = new ESMClass();
GeneralDataCoding coding = new GeneralDataCoding(8)
String text = "üöğçşə ƏIÖĞŞÇÜ";
String p = HexUtil.convertStringToHexString(text);
byte[] textByte = HexUtil.convertHexStringToBytes(p);

String messageId = session.submitShortMessage("CMT",TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL,
                   NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN,"1111", TypeOfNumber.INTERNATIONAL,
                   NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN, "phone_number", esmClass,
                   (byte) 0, (byte) 1, timeFormatter.format(new Date()), null,
                   new RegisteredDelivery(SMSCDeliveryReceipt.DEFAULT),
                   (byte) 0, coding, (byte) 0, textByte);
```

After this I get message with Chinese symbols. What is wrong?

Comment: Problem is solved. Problem is the HexUtil doesnot convert string correctly for unicode. For this use code from  here : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: can you please answer the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert string to hex string & use this data coding instead of that:

```
GeneralDataCoding dataCoding = new GeneralDataCoding(false, true, MessageClass.CLASS1, Alphabet.ALPHA_UCS2);
```

Get bytes:

```
byte[] textByte = text.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
```

This sample gives you send sms with this charset UCS2.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
byte[] textByte = text.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
```

`HexUtil` is a red herring here.